# Should angular $watch be removed when scope destroyed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Currently working on a project where we found huge memory leaks when not clearing broadcast subscriptions off destroyed scopes. The following code has fixed this:

```
var onFooEventBroadcast = $rootScope.$on('fooEvent', doSomething);

scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    //remove the broadcast subscription when scope is destroyed
    onFooEventBroadcast();
});
```

**Should this practice also be used for watches?** Code example below:

```
var onFooChanged = scope.$watch('foo', doSomething);

scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    //stop watching when scope is destroyed
    onFooChanged();
});
```

Comment: why don't you use `$on` on the current `$scope`? Subscriptions of the current `$scope` will be removed when the scope gets destroyed.

Comment: By the way you can simply pass the oFooEventBroadcast de-registration function as follows  $scope.$on('$destroy', onFooEventBroadcast) . That you don't need to call it yourself.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

No, you don't need to remove `$$watchers`, since they will effectively get removed once the scope is destroyed.

From Angular's source code (v1.2.21), `Scope`'s `$destroy` method:

```
$destroy: function() {
    ...
    if (parent.$$childHead == this) parent.$$childHead = this.$$nextSibling;
    if (parent.$$childTail == this) parent.$$childTail = this.$$prevSibling;
    if (this.$$prevSibling) this.$$prevSibling.$$nextSibling = this.$$nextSibling;
    if (this.$$nextSibling) this.$$nextSibling.$$prevSibling = this.$$prevSibling;
    ...
    this.$$watchers = this.$$asyncQueue = this.$$postDigestQueue = [];
    ...
```

So, the `$$watchers` array is emptied (and the scope is removed from the scope hierarchy).

Removing the `watcher` from the array is all the unregister function does anyway:

```
$watch: function(watchExp, listener, objectEquality) {
    ...
    return function deregisterWatch() {
        arrayRemove(array, watcher);
        lastDirtyWatch = null;
    };
}
```

So, there is no point in unregistering the `$$watchers` "manually".

---

You should still unregister event listeners though (as you correctly mention in your post) !

**NOTE:**
You only need to unregister listeners registered on other scopes. There is no need to unregister listeners registered on the scope that is being destroyed.
E.g.:

```
// You MUST unregister these
$rootScope.$on(...);
$scope.$parent.$on(...);

// You DON'T HAVE to unregister this
$scope.$on(...)
```

<sub>(Thx to @John for [pointing it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113884/should-angular-watch-be-removed-when-scope-destroyed/25114028?noredirect=1#comment-49039216))</sub>

Also, make sure you unregister any event listeners from elements that outlive the scope being destroyed. E.g. if you have a directive register a listener on the parent node or on `<body>`, then you must unregister them too.
<sub>Again, you don't have to remove a listener registered on the element being destroyed.</sub>

---

Kind of unrelated to the original question, but now there is also a `$destroyed` event dispatched on the element being destroyed, so you can hook into that as well (if it's appropriate for your usecase):

```
link: function postLink(scope, elem) {
  doStuff();
  elem.on('$destroy', cleanUp);
}
```

Comment: Another case would be when you a directive with isolated scope and you need to manually watch something on the parent scope:

```$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$parent.$watch(..));```

Comment: Actually, seems that there is **no need** to deregister event listeners **if they are registered on the scope that is being destroyed**. I mean:

`$scope.$on('fooEvent', doSomething); //No need to deregister`
`$rootScope.$on('fooEvent', doSomething); //$rootScope is never destroyed, you need to deregister this one 

Seen on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983696/angularjs-does-destroy-remove-event-listeners
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2723-unbinding-scope-on-event-handlers-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: @John: True, but in OP's code (see the question) they are registering listeners on the `$rootScope` and **must** be removed "manually".

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yup, just saying that maybe would be better to modify a bit that statement ;) I was ready to unbind every event on my scope when I read it, lol

Comment: @John: I just saw your updated comment. Good point. I will update the answer. Thx !

Comment: Does this also hold true, if we are watching a variable from rootScope in the current scope, does that watch also get deregistered on destroy ?

Comment: @gaurav5430, yes. It doesn't matter what is being watched, but who watches it (i.e. what scope is the watcher on). So, if you are calling `$scope.$watch(...)`, you don't need to deregister. If you are using `$rootScope.$watch(...)`, you do.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add too [@gkalpak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341938/gkalpak)'s answer as it lead me in the right direction..

The application I was working on created a memory leak by replacing directives whom had watches. The directives were replaced using jQuery and then complied.

To fix i added the following link function

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on('$destroy', function () {
        scope.$destroy();
    });
}
```

it uses the element destroy event to in turn destroy the scope.