# How to clean up left over $watches

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

We interop our angularJS web components with a jqxGrid. When the user edits in a cell, we create a custom typeahead editor (written in angular). When the editor is destroyed, I noticed that my $watches array doesn't return back to the previous value.

I am creating a new isolateScope for my directive, which I then compile and then append to the DOM element that JQX passes to me when the editor is needed:

`var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
 var customEditor = $compile(directive)(scope);`

What do I have to do in order to clean up these $watches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its likely that the new scope you are creating via

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
```

Is not being destroyed by the jqxGrid once the jqxGrid is done with the editor.

To clean up the watches, you simply need to ensure that a call is made to

```
scope.$destroy();
```

The tricky part is figuring out when to execute the destroy call;  I believe the jqxGrid should raise events such as **beforeEdit** and **afterEdit** which you can subscribe to;  the place where the $destroy() call should be made is within an event handler for the **afterEdit** event.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to clean up watchers effectively. 
[Should angular $watch be removed when scope destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113884/should-angular-watch-be-removed-when-scope-destroyed) 
Hope this helps.